# Fine tuning a pretrained language model with Simple Transformers

Tags: python-3.x, huggingface-transformers, language-model, simpletransformers

In his article 'Language Model Fine-Tuning For Pre-Trained Transformers' Thilina Rajapakse (https://medium.com/skilai/language-model-fine-tuning-for-pre-trained-transformers-b7262774a7ee)
provides the following code snippet for fine-tuning a pre-trained model using the library `simpletransformers`:

```
from simpletransformers.language_modeling import LanguageModelingModel
import logging


logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
transformers_logger = logging.getLogger("transformers")
transformers_logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)

train_args = {
    "reprocess_input_data": True,
    "overwrite_output_dir": True,
}

model = LanguageModelingModel('bert', 'bert-base-cased', args=train_args)

model.train_model("data/train.txt", eval_file="data/text.txt")

model.eval_model("data/test.txt")
```

He then adds:

> We assume that you have combined all the text in your dataset into two
>   text files train.txt and test.txt which can be found in the data/
>   directory.

I have 2 questions:

**Question 1**

Does the highlighted sentence above implies that the entire corpus will be merged into one text file?  So assuming that the Training Corpus is comprised of 1,000,000 text files, are we supposed to merge them all in one text file with code like this?

```
import fileinput
with open(outfilename, 'w') as fout, fileinput.input(filenames) as fin:
    for line in fin:
        fout.write(line)
```

**Question 2**

I presume that I can use the pretrained model: `bert-base-multilingual-cased`.  Correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Question 1

Yes, the input to the `train_model()` and `eval_model()` methods need to be a single file.

*Dynamically loading from multiple files will likely be supported in the future*

## Question 2

Yes, you can use `bert-base-multilingual-cased` model.

You will find a much more detailed, updated guide on language model training [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-electra-and-training-an-electra-language-model-3d33e3a9660d?source=friends_link&sk=2b4b4a79954e3d7c84ab863efaea8c65).

*Source - I am the creator of the library*

Comment: I was having exactly the same confusion. So, just to confirm. Does it mean the train.txt and test.txt are in fact the same file?